# ¿hay alguna forma que con Input Mask plugin algun caracter especial no sea estatico?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Estoy usando Input Mask plugin para rellenar un input

$('#tamano').inputmask({"mask": "(99999,99)"});

el funciona asi pero es estatico yo necesito agregar la cantidad de numeros que sean necesarios y en caso de necesitar usar la coma para colocar decimales lo haga.

¿Hay alguna forma de pasarle una configuración que haga eso?

Comment: quieres decir, usar variables?

Comment: osea si tiene alguna configuracion que se pueda usar para yo poder agregar x cantidad de numeros hasta cumplir con la cantidad de numeros que yo le ponga como limite y si es necesario que ponga decimales se los ponga si no no, es asi todo estatico siempre porque me sale asi (_ _ _ _ . _ _) no se si me entiendes